# Find and get image from hub

Tags: docker

I found needed image of `Centos6 32` bit on hub:

https://hub.docker.com/r/i386/centos/

Trying to run on my PC:

```
sudo docker run -it i386/centos6
```

Got error:

```
Unable to find image 'i386/centos6:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for i386/centos6, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
```

How to get required image?

Comment: [There is no i386/centos6:latest](https://hub.docker.com/r/i386/centos/tags/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On docker hub page go to the tags tab. there are only `6` and `cenos6` tag.

```
sudo docker pull i386/centos:6
```